# How do I repair NVIZ error: 'Can't find a usable init.tcl'?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

How do I repair the following problem:

[image: NVIZ error]

The error occurred while I was trying to run NVIZ in the GRASS environment in QGIS.  NVIZ however runs perfectly in GRASS.  On checking the directories listed, init.tcl is located there.

Comment: Not sure if you are using the latest version of QGIS, but.. did you tried already to uninstall and install it again (with the last version of QGIS)? Do you have Windows 64bit ??

Comment: I am using the latest version of QGIS and have tried to uninstall and reinstall, but it doesn't work (seems to keep everything in memory and I'm not sure how to clear that).  I'm using Windows 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Please reinstall the Tcl/TK and the Python packages from OSGeo4W. It will solve the dependency problem.

Comment: Thanks!  How do I do that exactly?  I'm rather a newbie at this...

Comment: I think (while not having Windows myself) that you launch the OSGeo4W wizard and then select the packages in question for re-installation (there should be a checkbox toggle to do so, it is rather intuitive). Probably they are available within the "advanced" stuff section.